# `find` multiple -o -name condition AND ! -name

Tags: centos, find

I'd been playing with this snippet and seems like I can't make my desired `find` work. I tried google but all tutorials does not seem to tackle this scenario

suppose i have the following files

```
test-[done].mkv
test.mkv
test2.avi
test3.mp4
```

what i want is for my `find` to select all `.mkv OR .avi OR .mp4` BUT NOT those with `[done]` on its name

the first condition can be easily solve using

`find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) -print`

but I am having trouble doing the second condition, trying

`find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) ! \( ! -name '*[done]*' \) -print`

still shows the `test-[done].mkv

```
test-[done].mkv
test.mkv
test2.avi
test3.mp4
```

trying regex because I thought there's limit to how many -name can be used, but still no luck

```
[root@xxxx]# ls
test-[done].mkv  test.mkv  test2.avi  test3.mp4
[root@xxxx]# find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) ! \( -regex '.*\(\[done\]\)$' \) -print
test-[done].mkv
test.mkv
test2.avi
test3.mp4
```

Can somebody please help me how to work on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your `-name` version, instead of `! -name '*[done]*'` you need `! -name '*\[done\]*'` - otherwise it's taking the letters in brackets as a character set, and thus excluding anything that includes the letter "d" or "o" or "n" or "e" (and all of your filenames contain "e").  You were then negating that condition a second time, so that rather than excluding all files it includes all files - but a corrected version would be:

```
find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) \( ! -name '*\[done\]*' \) -print
```

Your regex version is wrong because you have the `$` immediately after the pattern matching `[done]`, but in your real file name there's still a file extension after that point - but adding a `.*` before the `$` does work.

```
find * \( -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*avi' -o -name '*mp4' -o -name '*flv' -o -name '*ogg' -o -name '*mov' \) ! \( -regex '.*\(\[done\]\).*$' \) -print
```